# can a professional distinguish between a previously sunk foundation and a currently sinking foundation?

Tags: basement, foundation, slab

I bought a house with the understanding that the foundation *had* sunk some, but that the structural problem had been permanently fixed and stabilized (with steel columns) in late 2019. However, I'm beginning to suspect that this is not entirely true; I'm beginning to suspect that parts of the foundation (possibly but not necessarily the section that was reinforced) are still sinking.

In general (because I don't really have specifics to provide), if I were to hire a foundation inspector, would they be able to tell me whether my foundation is currently sinking? Or does the fact that it *had* sunk a few years back make it impossible to determine whether it's *currently* sinking?

Comment: My next-door neighbor had a structural engineer look at his foundation cracks and received an opinion that the cracks didn't look like they had emerged recently. But, that's just an opinion.

Comment: Cracks that are clean and fresh compared to cracks full of cr!p or debris…

Comment: As RibaldEddie has already answered, a series of (precision) measurements over time is the definitive way to be sure, opinion-free. And an engineer is the person who can do those to the precision required. So many home inspectors, of which I'd class foundation inspectors without a *P.E.* after their name as a subset, are hacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The professional way to determine this is to measure the movement of the foundation over time. If you start measuring today and check regularly to see if the measurement is changing (and by how much), and you find that it's not changing now, then you can be fairly confident that settling is not currently occurring. If you measure and determine that there is a change now, then it's currently occurring. You can use the rate of movement to work backwards and estimate when the settling had begun.

So, in short: hire a structural engineer to help you set up a measurement regimen and you can find out.